# Python- No module named "src"

Tags: python, import, module, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am trying to import my module name "src" into the "data_ingestion.py" file but the VS code, terminal showing this error "No module named src" Why VS code is not detecting my module?

The pics of the problem are given:

[image]

Is it a problem with the virtual environment? OR it is a Run time error?

I linked the file with ".venv" by going to settings>select interpreter>python 3.11.8(".venv":venv).I thought that maybe".venv" was not linked to the data_ingestion.py file. If this is the problem then please tell me how can I solve this.

I have also tried giving the full file path to the VS code terminal but that also does not work.

Comment: It's more convenient to just embed images on stackoverflow. Not links to images.

Comment: @Pycm They don't have enough rep to embed images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

File, folder structure,

```
parentfolder
  code.py
  folder 
    script.py
```

In python, to import your scripts, functions you should use **relative paths** or absolute paths.
So, when you import like,

```
from folder.script import function
```

The folder should be sub folder of where the script is.

**----------------------------------------**

2)

File, folder structure,

```
parentfolder
  script.py 
  folder 
    code.py
```

So, maybe try like below.

```
from .folder.script import function
```

Which is import "function" from a "script.py" file from parent folder called "folder".